# How to get or store the Current System's year to a variable?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

here's the concept of my program.
there is a combobox that has year (from 1915-present) and textBox that will display the Age.

here's my idea

```
Dim today as integer'this is where i want to store the current year    
Dim year as integer'stores selected items from combobox
Dim age as Integer      
year = combobox.selectedItem
age = year - today 
txtbox.text = age 'displays age on textbox
```

Comment: ok fine, Whats wrong with your idea? is there any error you are getting?

Comment: my problem is how to get the value of current year? depending on the system's date

Answer (score 1):

For getting the actual year: Today.year. More: you need to pass a string to the TextBox. Age is integer, so you need convert in string. I have tried this, and it seems to work properly:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim year As Integer = Today.Year

    For i As Integer = 1915 To year
        comboBox.Items.Add(CStr(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim yearToday As Integer = Today.Year

    Dim year As Integer          'stores selected items from combobox
    Dim age As Integer

    year = CInt(comboBox.SelectedItem)
    age = yearToday - year
    txtBox.Text = age.ToString 'displays age on textbox
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display an AGE, it´s interesting to know the month of birth, since, depending of that month and the current month you will have a difference (for more or for less) of 1 years.

Try something like this:

```
   Dim MyBirth As String = Inputbox("When had you borned (dd/mm/yyyy)?")
   Dim Age As String = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, CDate(MyBirth), Today).ToString

   msgbox( "You are " & Age & " years old")
```